# Question about polynomials with rational coefficients

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f$ and $g$ two polynomials with rational coefficients of degree $n$, $n \geq 1$. They share a same root $r$ and $f$ is irreductible. Prove that $f | g$.

I tried writing $f=(x-r)h$ where $h$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ but didn’t know what to do next. Please help me with a basic proof.

Comment: So $f,g$ have the same degree, is that correct, with $r$ non-rational?

Comment: $gcd(f,g)$ cannot be $1$ since they share a root, so it must be $f$ since $f$ irreducible, so $f$ divides $g$

Comment: Conrad, I can’t understand your proof.